# What is this Nielsen advert about and where is the question they promised?

Tags: support, advertising

I just got an advert in the sidebar of Stack Overflow asking me to take a one question survey with a partner. Ok, sure.

[image: advert]

The link leads here:

```
https://secure-gl.imrworldwide.com/u/t/00/05/19/90/offsite_survey.html?ce=stackoverflow&ci=nlsnci1469&am=3&r=1486740994879
```

When I click it, I get a page thanking me for participating. But I didn't answer any questions.

[image: result]

**They promised me a question! Where is it?**

[image: freehand circles!]

Jokes aside, I think if they say there is a question and that its content has been reviewed, they should at least ask a question. This is not only confusing, but it impacts the users' trust in these kinds of partners. I don't mind answering a question or two that don't contain personal information if I know that it will help to pay for Stack Exchange services, but this was just odd.

Comment: I'm sure this is just a mistake in how the campaign was set up. Our ad team will look into it shortly.

Comment: @TimPost I just realized the last sentence sounds way harsher than it was intended. I wanted to report it, and rated it **** and _other_ and hoped there was a text box, but there was not.

Comment: The question was "do advertisements on SO draw enough views and clicks".  The kind of thing Nielsen measures.  You answered it :)

Comment: @HansPassant I thought so too. That's why I clicked it a bunch more times.

Comment: Hmm, it is not that easily fooled.  Want a cookie?

Comment: My guess is that Nielsen decided based on your country, or maybe some other information revealed by the click, that they weren't interested in your answer. My mom was recently asked to participate in a lengthy survey by an organization she belongs to and it turned out they only needed to ask one question, "Are you over 75?".

Comment: I came into this question thinking Nielsen had promised to post a real programming question on SO.

Comment: The question is: what is the question?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I work in ad ops at Stack Overflow and we're currently looking into this issue. The normal workflow should have prompted you with a question upon clicking that ad. We'll update here as we find more info.

UPDATE:

After running the ad through Q&A the only way we were able to replicate your experience was on a browser that had already filled out the survey. The client is using a cookie to prevent multiple responses from the same user. The cookie that you should be able to find in your browser is from "imrworldwide". If you would like to take the survey, you will need to remove that cookie, and then click the ad again. I hope this helps!

Comment: And here I thought the question was implied: "do you want to fill out a survey?" :)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. If I delete the cookies from that domain and revisit the URL in my question I get a new cookie and the same "thank you" page. Possibly that URL is already for the thank you, but I don't have the original URL any more.

Comment: @AdamLear Great. Now I've got that stupid "Frozen" song stuck in my head. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TiesonT. It hasn't even got the right syllable pattern for that song! :-/

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "Do you wanna take a surveeyyy?"

Comment: @NateBarbettini "Take" has one syllable. "Fill out" has two.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I know. I was trying to fit it to the right syllable pattern so it would get stuck in your head too.

Comment: @TiesonT. Great, now you got it stuck in my head when I tried to figure out how it got stuck in your head.

Comment: @TiesonT.: Let it go.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ...ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @WillWestendorf does QA check for run-on sentences in ad copy?

Comment: maybe there's a tuned adblocker at work here... I run ublock origin and privacy badger, and whitelist various domains and resources, which makes for a pretty variable user experience for me on the web in general!